# Excel - Convert date from yymmdd to dd/mm/yy

Tags: string, excel, date

I have an Excel file which is exported from a Access database.

I have `25000` records and I will need to replace all of them.

The date column is not formatted (yymmdd). I need to change the date format from yymmdd to dd/mm/19yy. For the `yy` I need to add a constant value `19` in front of it so it would be `19yy`.

**I have only 1 date column per row**

Is there any way to convert all the `25000` record's column formatted in `yymmdd` to `dd/mm/19yy` in a few clicks?. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you the result as an actual date which you can then format as you wish using Excel's date formatting options.

`=DATE(1900+LEFT(A1,2), MID(A1,3,2), RIGHT(A1,2))`

Comment: +1....note you will actually get the same result if you omit 1900+ because in date function 88 will be interpreted as 1988 anyway, so this version works too `=DATE(LEFT(A1,2), MID(A1,3,2), RIGHT(A1,2))`

Comment: @barryhoudini, that might be true of 88, but it's probably not true of 01. I'm inferring from the original question that all dates are prior to 2000, but if that's wrong he'll have to be more careful.

Comment: 01 would give you 1901......`DATE(1,11,17)=DATE(1901,11,17)`. It's different between DATE function and "text dates" - `="11/17/01"+0` (assuming default m/d/yy settings) will give you `Nov 17 2001` - the cutoff point in that case is determined by regional settings as per my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to parse it into a date value, but merely need to display a date in the format you identified, the following will work on a value in cell `A1` (copy down to the rest of the 25,000 values as needed:

```
=RIGHT(A1,2) & "/" & MID(A1,3,2) & "/19" & LEFT(A1,2)
```

In my cell `A1`, I entered the value `981116`. This formula converted it to `16/11/1998`. I think that's what you're looking for, right?

Comment: The value of the column is different through all records. Is it possible to copy all the formula down?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data starts at A2 put this formula in B2

`=(19&TEXT(A1,"00-00-00"))+0`

**Now format B2 in required date format, e.g. mm/dd/yyyy**

and you can easily "fill down" all 25000 rows by doing this:

put cursor on bottom right of B2 (first cell with formula) until you see a black "+" - that's the "fill-handle" - double click and the formula will populate as far down as you have continuous data in the adjacent column

Note: you can probably omit the **19&** if all your dates are after **1930** because the default is to treat any date written without the century as 1900s if it's >=30 or 2000s if it's <30 [although you can change that in regional settings]

Comment: Nice and simple.. Useful how excel converts to number when you +0