# Excel formula: input just 4 digits excel converts to date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Following up on this earlier question: [Excel - Convert date from yymmdd to dd/mm/yy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022109/excel-convert-date-from-yymmdd-to-dd-mm-yy)

I would like to input only 4 digits and the formula convert to a date.

For example, if I enter value 1207, the formula will convert into 12/07/2014 but if I input 0311 it converts into 31/1/2014.

I couldn't work out how to do the date conversion when I input a date starting with "0" such as 0711.

The formula I'm using:

```
=LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&MID(A2,3,4)&"/2014"&RIGHT(A2,0)
```

See the wrong output highlighted below:

```
Input   Date converted          
1112    11/12/2014      
1503    15/03/2014      
2407    24/07/2014      
2912    29/12/2014       
0712    71/2/2014 <~~~~~~   should be 07/12/2014    
0311    31/1/2014 <~~~~~~   should be 03/11/2014
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't post the formula i'm using :( =LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&MID(A2,3,4)&"/2014"&RIGHT(A2,0)

Comment: What you have done is not wrong but now you have to format the cell as dd/mm/yyyy. Hence, its always preferable to use DATE function which will format the string to date for you. Hence no need to format the cell as date.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you edited the other formula, but it should be working. In any case, there's one that works for your particular case:

```
=DATE(2014, RIGHT(A2,2), LEFT(A2,2))
```

Where A2 contains the date.

---

If your dates are actually numbers, then you might want to use a condition to change the result if the number is of different length:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=4, DATE(2014,RIGHT(A2,2),LEFT(A2,2)), DATE(2014,RIGHT(A2,2),LEFT(A2,1)))
```

Comment: @ZAT Indeed! I wrongly assumed initially that they were text, since I rarely do number formats with leading zeroes and actually convert my number to text when I do due to the nature of my work ^^;

Answer (score 2):

You can use the formula as suggested by Jerry. I have same formula:

`=DATE(2014,RIGHT(A2,2),LEFT(A2,2))`

But, You need to make sure that your inputs are text. 0712 should be displayed as 0712 in excel. i.e keep you input to **four digits** then only this above formula will work. You can use apostrophe before 0712 to convert it as text, enter '0712 as input.

Comment: Thank you so much Paresh J. I have format the column into text and the formula works fine.

Comment: @Paresh J If Jerry's answer needed some edit you could edit that or suggested something there, rather creating a new answer.

Comment: @ZAT: you are right!!! But I preferred to create my answer since he may or may not agree to my edited answer.